# See what Rails 7 is actually returning in JSON from the Controller

Tags: json, ruby-on-rails

I keep getting and unexpected response error from EasyMDE (markdown editor) upon image uploading in Rails 7.

The exact error I get is this: EasyMDE: Received an unexpected response after uploading the image.200 (OK)

However, the image uploads correctly to active storage - it just does not send the correct response back. Code is below.

First the Stimulus controller that is bringing EasyMDE to the textarea:

```
import { Controller } from "@hotwired/stimulus"
import EasyMDE from "easymde"


export default class extends Controller {
  connect() {
    const easyMDE = new EasyMDE({
         hideIcons: ["side-by-side", "fullscreen", "guide", "image"],
         showIcons: ["code", "upload-image"],
         uploadImage: true,
         imageUploadEndpoint: '/articles/attach'     
    })
  }
}
```

The model:

```
class ArticleImage < ApplicationRecord
  has_one_attached :image
end
```

And now the controller:

```
class ArticleImagesController < ApplicationController
  skip_before_action :verify_authenticity_token, only: :attach
  def attach
        attachment = ArticleImage.create! image: params[:image]
        render json: { filename: url_for(attachment.image) }
    end
end
```

Is there a way to dump the JSON and see what exactly is sending back to EasyMDE or is there another method I should try?